# Fluid Dynamics - Streamline Separation and Flow Velocity

Tags: differential-geometry, fluid-dynamics

Consider the following quote:

> "... The velocity distribution outside the boundary layer can be determined from the spacing of the streamlines. Since there can be no flow across streamlines, we would expect the flow velocity to increase in regions where the spacing between streamlines decreases. Conversely, an increase in streamline spacing implies a decrease in flow velocity."
> "... For inviscid flow, an increase in velocity is accompanied by a decrease in pressure; Conversely, a decrease in velocity is accompanied by an increase in pressure." (pgs.36-37 [1])

Now, let me clarify a few definitions: A **velocity distribution** is in this context, a time-dependent vector field; **Inviscid** means non-viscous; A **boundary layer** develops in a neighborhood of a solid surface due to the "*no-slip condition*"; And a **streamline** is a time-dependent curve that, at each instant, is everywhere tangent to the velocity distribution. 
To put this last one in math language:
$$\color{blue}{\forall t:\forall s:[\partial_s\gamma_{stream,p_0}(s,t) = \partial_t\theta(\gamma(s,t),t) = X_{\gamma(s,t)}(t)]}$$
The parameter-derivative of the streamline through $p_0$ at $\gamma(s,t)$ equals the flow velocity at that point.

**Note that the above is my own notation adapted from differential geometry notation for flows and vector fields. This definition differs from that of say wiki (but is similar). The text I'm working from doesn't articulate.*

---

**Question:** 
Can we prove the statements in the block quote using this definition in blue and the definition of pressure as Force/Area?

---

[1] *Fox, Robert W.; McDonald, Alan T.*, Introduction to fluid mechanics., New York, NY: Wiley. xvi, 781 p. (1994). [ZBL0812.76001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0812.76001).)

Answer (score 1):

This relationship can be observed for *internal flows* (such as through a pipe) by way of **conservation of mass**. If a fluid is *incompressible*, forcing in fluid one end will force fluid out the other in equal amounts. Since mass is related to volume by density and density is assumed constant, we have:
$$m_{in}/V_{in}= \rho_{constant} = m_{out}/V_{out}$$
$$\implies V_{in} = V_{out}.$$
So importantly, if we constrict the pipe, we necessarily have to compensate with an elongation to equate volumes. Say for example:
$$\pi r^2h = \pi\bigg(\frac{r}{2}\bigg)^2(4h).$$
If we have the same volume per second in as out, with the same height of both cylinders, it must be the case that (in the example) 4 smaller volumes worth of fluid pass through in the same instant. Based on this argument, we could say the outbound fluid has greater velocity.
Since the fluid is constricted by the pipe, naturally streamlines will be pushed together. We may compare initial and final geometries with a *homotopy*, which in theory would detail streamline distance throughout the transition in laminar flow.
From the reverse viewpoint, one could then quantify how streamline separation implies volume/geometry changes, which as we've seen yields a velocity comparison. To be explicit here would give the desired result for the first statement. I think experimental relations would be more useful and allow for more variables.
Just to state it, sources I have looked up call this volume per second equality the *continuity equation*.

---

The second statement is more tricky and everything I do with $P = F/A$ seems to contradict the assertion. In our example, increase in velocity is accompanied by decrease in area, which the equation says leads to *increase* in pressure. Fellow Stack Members, I defer to you!

Comment: Writing it as a comment to not steal away points; the answer to the second statement cannot come from a purely geometric statement, but from a relation between the velocity field and the pressure field that is separate from geometric/streamline concerns. For inviscid flows, that relationship is Bernoulli's law, which indeed agrees with OP's pressure/velocity statements.

Comment: Thank you for the response! So it is like an empirical law, not something we can necessarily prove?

Comment: Ultimately, yes; that being said, you can derive it from more sophisticated models. For example, you can derive Bernoulli's law for steady flows by integrating the Navier-Stokes equations judiciously when the viscosity of the liquid is zero. You can derive /those/ equations from the Cauchy momentum equation along with suitable assumptions from kinetic theory, and so on.

Comment: So I found this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fq8zqRRBEEY that seems to explain it almost to my understanding in terms of P = F/A, but it seems he like reads it backwards. Higher velocity region has larger force in free body diagram, but that would translate to higher pressure via the equation?

Comment: The video skips a small, but in your case, crucial step; the connection between the net forces on the particle and the pressure distribution. For example, what indicates that the net force on the particle isn't coming from viscous drag instead of pressure? The answer comes from Bernoulli's law (and the assumptions required to use it), or in this case what happens when you take the spatial derivative of it on both sides. In the absence of external forces, Bernoulli's law requires that /all/ accelerations of fluid parcels stem from pressure gradients, and viceversa.

Comment: I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding on the definition of pressure. I thought it was to be applied to discs spanning the internal structure of the pipe. We seem to be discussing it on a fluid particle (mini cube/sphere/cylinder say). I will look into Bernoulli some more in Ch.6 of this text (currently on 3/4)...